# Remove top level category from URL (add_rewrite_rule)

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to remove the top level category from my URL, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have set my permalink custom structure to `/%category%/%postname%/` but this is adding all of the categories to my URL. My post category structure looks like the follow:

- Parent

  - Child1
  - Child2
  - Child3

URL: `www.domain.com/parent/child1/post-title`

What I am looking for: `www.domain.com/child1/post-title` (top level `parent` removed)

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? I think I need a `add_rewrite_rule`, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );
function build_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy( 'category', 'post', array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
'query_var' => 'category_name',
'rewrite' => did_action( 'init' ) ? array(
'hierarchical' => false,
'slug' => get_option('category_base') ? get_option('category_base') : 'category',
'with_front' => false) : false,
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'_builtin' => true,
) );
}
```

Comment: Also please see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category